# Django Models Filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following:

```
def foo(self):
    print "Test"
    scores = BasicScore.objects.filter(event__id=self.id).order_by('score_date')[0:1]
    print scores
    #return s
    #return Score.objects.all().order_by('start_date')[:1]
    return scores
```

And in my Template:

```
event.foo.0.value
```

This will work fine and I will be able to use BasicScore class.

However previously I had:
    
    return scores[0]

But I got this in the logs:

```
Test

[]
```

And the exception:

```
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    

list index out of range

Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __getitem__, line 207
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

I'm a little new to Django/Python, but why would the list of one return successfully, but accessing [0] end up erroring with accessing an empty set?

Comment: You seem to be talking about two separate revisions of the code ("previously I had").  Show one piece of code, and clearly explain what seems wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

The list `[]` is not a list of one, it is a list of zero, and `scores[0]` should raise an `IndexError`.

Comment: When I return return scores, and access element 0 as event.foo.0.value
 I get something to print in the template.

Comment: Sure, so when I had the following: 

    return scores


I could access scores in my Django template as

    event.foo.0.value
    
And it will work.

However when I return just:

return scores[0]

 it blows up and gives me the index exception.

Comment: Try changing `scores = BasicScore...` to `scores = list(BasicScore...)`

Comment: Just not acting as I would suspect:

Tried list(wrap my DB call) and return scores[0] failed. list(...) and return scores will work though.